# How to prevent winsock application from disconnecting due to network inactivity (c++)

Tags: c++, timeout, winsock2

Currently have a winsock application that connects to a server. It can send and receive packets, but after a few minutes(around 2, if you wanted me to guess) of not sending anything, it disconnects and I have restart it, which is pretty annoying. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless there is a very aggressive connection-dropping firewall in the way, this can only be due to bugs in the client or server, or disagreements about the application protocol between them.

Comment: Well, the obvious way to get around that would be to send something to the server once a minute...

Comment: Yes. How do I do this?

Comment: SO_KEEPALIVE: Enables sending keep-alive packets for a socket connection -- see my answer below

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem? If so, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting KEEPALIVE to true.  You set this using the socket options. You have to set it on both the client socket and the server's listening socket.

Have a look at:
http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt
And
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx